# Weird behavior involving sleeping in Windows 10

Tags: laptop, windows-10, sleep, hibernate

I've never encountered this before. I put my laptop in sleep mode and I can see the flashing light notifying it's in sleep mode OK. Almost every time when I open the lid back it will be waken up from sleeping mode and go right into the welcome screen (of course without any laptop manufacturer's logo appeared).

However sometimes after my laptop has been sleeping, when I come back it looks almost like being it had been turned off before (no flashing light). But it's not actually turned off. When I press the power button, it appears really like it starts from turned-off state (the manufacturer's logo appears then the loading screen of Windows 10). But after it's loaded ***all the windows and applications I opened before are still there***. It looks really like what hibernating does. But I wonder how it could hibernate my laptop while it's already put in sleep mode? Is this some kind of new feature in Windows 10?

Comment: How are you putting the computer to sleep?  Is your power plan is configured to hibernate when the lid is closed?

Comment: I've observed similar behavior on Windows 7.  I believe that it is transitioning from sleep to hibernation, and I suspect that it does it if too much time passes or the battery gets too low.

Comment: @LevenTech I can confirm that the action for closing the lid is sleep the computer. Right after closing the lid, I can see it's in sleep mode, but such as for some minutes later I come back it may look totally like being shutdown or hibernated. Also this happens occasionally, sometimes it's just normal as what I expect.

Comment: @Scott I've never encountered that in Windows 7, also Hibernating requires a lot of operations to write data to disk. Right after it sleeping I don't think my laptop can do that much to switch to hibernate state. That's why it's hard to understand what's going on. BTW my laptop battery is not that bad, in sleep mode it can endure for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your computer is either

1) Waking up on a timer to transition from sleep to hibernate according to your power plan. If you have set your computer to sleep after some time and hibernate after some more time, *or* to hibernate on low battery, then the computer will wake up to do exactly that.

2) Using hybrid sleep and running out of battery. In Hybrid Sleep Windows will both Sleep and Hibernate at the same time. If the power is not lost, then it will simply resume from sleep. If power is lost for any reason, it will resume from hibernate instead - giving you the best of both worlds.

Comment: Well I think it's due to the so-called ***hybrid sleep*** but it may work in the way as what I commented to the answer of Roh_mish. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid sleep + Quick boot.

Windows 8 and above have this feature. Although Windows 10 does things a bit differently. If you are on battery, It will hibernate after a short period. OR when the power is lost.

Also check your power options to see if you have set it to hibernate when you are on battery and to sleep only if charging.

Comment: I've never heard about hybrid sleep and just found out more about it and know that it should be turned off by default on laptop. However I do see the settings to hibernate the laptop after 180 minutes (while it should sleep after 30 minutes). Looks like it prepares for hibernation right when it puts my laptop in sleep mode, then when the time comes it switch to hibernation easily (even when the laptop is sleeping).